# Adding base62 numbers

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

Say, one's got a base62 number (alphabet: [aAbBcC-yYzZ0-9]) `char *num="abcd"`. *The alphabet used to create such a number consists of letters in non-alphabetical order! ('A' after 'a', not 'b')*.

How to get the next number of the sequence (how to add 1 to base62 number)? Next is "abce" and previous is "abcc". I'd appreciate it if you provide me with some code.

Comment: Wouldn't that be base *52*?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, ow, I'm sorry, gonna correct it

Comment: letters, uppercase and lowers, *and numbers (digits)* is 62

Comment: Clarified question in a late edit.

Answer (score 2):

The usually-best answer to questions such as *How do I compute in base N ?* is

> convert from base-N to base-2 (trivial if `N==2`, easy enough
>   otherwise), use the lightning-fast, hardware-implemented features of
>   your computer to calculate in base-2, then convert from base-2 to
>   base-N.

While rejecting my absurd suggestion consider how your computer fools you into thinking that it does base-10 arithmetic.

Note carefully that this approach complies with OP's strict instruction to avoid converting numbers to base-10.

Comment: Wow, to tell the truth, I never thought about base-2. That's a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the order of the "digits" (like e.g. the string `"05DprPaGAg"`) then it's quite easy. To increase by one, find the letter in the digit-order string and get the next letter, to decrease by one find the letter in the digit-order string and get the previous letter.

If the digit you want to decrease is the lowest digit (the `0` in the example alphabet), then decrease the second least significant digit (by using the method described above) and use the highest digit for the least significant digit of the number to decrease. Do the opposite for increase.

Comment: ... but when you "increase" 25 to 0, you have to shift left also and add 1. i.e. "carry the one"

Comment: OK, if I want to do this about 1e9 times, that'll be _extremely_ slow, won't it?

Comment: @ForceBru Doing that many operations will take time no matter the algorithms, but it can be offset by using better data structures. For example, if you're programming in C++ you could use e.g. `std::map` to map each digit to a `std::pair` that contains the next and previous digits. (Note: I don't actually know if that will be more effective than searching a string.)

Comment: @ForceBru No, it'll be extremely fast. Zillions of times faster than you could do it yourself without a computer. It won't be as fast as doing the same operations in base 2 or base 10 with a computer, of course. Perhaps that's one reason that we tend not to use base 62.

Answer (score 0):

1. Map each character to a digit it represents(in base 62).
2. Use simple addition like you would do it manually(carrying the one if necessary, starting from the right-most position).
3. Subtraction can be performed in almost the same manner(starting from the right-most position and carrying a "minus one" to the left if required).

Comment: @ForceBru It is not necessary to use a map to map characters to something. You can use a simple array, where `digit[c]` is the digit that the `c` character represents.

Comment: @ForceBru, if you want pure C, you should remove the [c++] tag from the question

Comment: @AaronMcDaid, I've put two tags, so I'd prefer to get answers concerned to both C and C++