# Working with base-2 in C

Tags: c, numbers

Some time ago I got this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28195771/4354477) to my question. Yes, we can define a number in hex format as `int a=0x12;`. There are some tricks to convert `1011` into 11. The data is passed as ordinary base-10 numbers.

Here is my question: how do we work with base-2 numbers in C? The goal is to add some numbers using that *lightning-fast* processing.

Comment: The computer works with the numbers in 'lightning-fast' binary.  The only issue is how they're presented to you, the user/programmer.  The `strtol()` family of functions can be used to convert binary notation text (`"1011"`  for 11, etc) into binary numbers internally.  There isn't a standard way to convert internal binary numbers to binary text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any literal number will be converted to the computer's native format (binary) during compilation.

It doesn't matter which base your literal uses, once the program runs the number is exactly the same.

If you do:

```
int a = 4711;
```

The number "4711" is *not* stored in decimal anywhere once the program runs.

If you do arithmetic on it:

```
int b = 42;

printf("4711+42=%d\n", a + b);
```

the computer is *not* doing "decimal arithmetic", it's adding the native (binary) numbers.

Comment: That's right, so, decimal computer arithmetic is as fast as binary one?

Comment: @ForceBru You're completely missing the point. There is no "decimal arithmetic" happening here. Perhaps you're thinking of "bignum" libraries, which are used to work with numbers that are too big for the computer's processor to handle as single entities.

Comment: that guy, whose answer is linked to my question, talked about 'base-2' conversion or something like that. So, I thought he was right and started googling. A few moments later I realized that computer always works with base-2 and got stuck, unable to get his idea.